'square' control box using the 'quantikz' package on overleaf/latex
How to get the 'square' control box using the 'quantikz' package on overleaf/latex? The only options available are filled and unfilled circles. Here is the quantum circuit diagram for reference.

The $\TeX$ StackExchange would probably be a better place for this kind of question. An empty gate and a vertical wire should do the trick.

Please try to make the title shorter and put the actual question into its body.

@AG47 Technically, yes, but as the package author (i.e. me) hangs out here, I'm more likely to see it here....

Out of interest, what is the context of needing a square control? It's not one I've ever seen before.

@DaftWullie, the square control suggests a more general form of control-target operations. For example, the square control-U in the figure implies for q[0] = 0 results in action of u_{1} q[1], and q[0] = 1 results in u_{2} q[1]. (U is block diagonal with u_{1} and u_{2} along the diagonal)

This depends on how much control you want over the size of the square. As @AG47 says, your first port of call could just be an empty gate and a vertical wire. It's a bit big for my taste.
Instead, you can more directly add a square to the relevant cell, but to avoid adding to the size of the cell, it's safer to add an upward wire from the cell below.
\begin{quantikz}
& \ctrl{1} &\gate{}\wire[d]{q}& |[operator]| & \\
& \gate{U} & \gate{U} & \gate{U}\wire[u]{q} &
\end{quantikz}

The effect is as follows:

The box size is controlled using inner sep. For example, if you want something even smaller, you could replace the operator part with
|[operator,inner sep=1pt]|


Would you mind explaining how the pipes and brackets work? I have seen them when I looked into \linethrough but couldn't figure it out.

Thank you, DaftWullie! This works perfectly for me. Additionally, I realized I was not using the updated 'quantikz' package.
'\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}' has to be added to the preamble for the document.

@AG47 They're a tikzmatrix thing, a way of supplying tikz style options to an individual cell/node of the tikzmatrix. See: https://tikz.dev/library-matrix
